# Ensure minimum distance between adjacent points

Tags: r

I have a list/frame of 15-25 datapoints. They're all between 0 and 100, and there are some clusters (like around 72). When displaying this data I want to increase the distance between every pair of points so it's at least 2 (eg 69.4 and 71.4 would be two adjacent points).

However I need to ensure I preserve overall order and keep every point as close as possible to where it was originally.

My list of points is simply

```
scores <- c(13.343, 17.998, 25.413, 27.721, 33.361, 47.263, 52.298, 55.981,
            57.851, 72.038, 72.204, 72.296, 73.472, 75.925, 80.748, 85.998)
```

I want to increase the distance between the clusters of points. The points at 72.038 - 72.296 would all move down to ensure a more even spread.

```
spacedScores <- c(13.343, 17.998, 25.413, 27.721, 33.361, 47.263, 52.298,
                  55.981, 57.851, 67.925, 69.925, 71.925, 73.925, 75.925,
                  80.748, 85.998)
```

Any suggestions on how to do this most cleanly in R?

Clarifications: I'm not necessarily looking for a mathematically optimal solution, just something pretty good. I also image most of the time some points will need to move up and some points down - that's good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `diff(scores)` to find the distance between points (I'm assuming values are sorted).

Then use `which(diff(scores) < 2)` to identify "bad points" and move them back so that the spacing = 2.

Problem is, moving one point to correct one distance may make the previous or next distance become < 2, so you'll have to repeat this several times.

Here's an example where I "brute force" the solution. You may want to introduce a counter to avoid infinite loop

```
scores <- c(13.343, 17.998, 25.413, 27.721, 33.361, 47.263,
    52.298, 55.981, 57.851, 72.038, 72.204, 72.296, 73.472, 
    75.925, 80.748, 85.998)
spacedScores <- c(13.343, 17.998, 25.413, 27.721, 33.361, 
    47.263, 52.298, 55.981, 57.851, 67.925, 69.925, 71.925, 
    73.925, 75.925, 80.748, 85.998)

plot(scores, pch=20)
points(spacedScores, pch='x', col="red")

badPoints <- which(diff(scores) < 2)

while (length(badPoints) > 0)
  {
  scores[badPoints] <- scores[badPoints] - (2 - diff(scores)[badPoints])
  badPoints <- which(diff(scores) < 2)
  }

points(scores, pch='o', col="green")
```

Here's the result: in black the original points, in green the modified points, in red the spaced points you supplied

[image: example plot]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I changed it slightly to push up and down by subtracting `((2.1-diff)/2)` and adding the same value to the next value above. Essentially just pushing away from each other by half the original dinstance, instead of just moving one the whole distance. This is fantastic, thanks. I also had to use 2.1 -..., that way it (shouldn't) get stuck in a loop it can't resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I made up a hackish bruteforce method which iterates a few times until every diff is greater than 2 with the smallest required modification in the dataset:

```
scores <- c(13.343, 17.998, 25.413, 27.721, 33.361, 47.263, 52.298, 55.981, 57.851, 72.038, 72.204, 72.296, 73.472, 75.925, 80.748, 85.998)

done <- 0
while (any(diff(scores)<2)) {
diffs <- diff(scores)
closevals <- which(diffs < 2)
first <- closevals[which.min(diffs[closevals])]
if (which.min(diff(scores[(first-1):(first+1)])) == 1) {
    scores[1:(first-1)] <- scores[1:(first-1)] - (2 - (scores[first] - scores[first-1]))
    } else {
        scores[(first+1):length(scores)] <- scores[(first+1):length(scores)] + (2 - (scores[first+1] - scores[first]))
    }
}
> scores
 [1] 13.343 17.998 25.413 27.721 33.361 47.263 52.298 55.981 57.981 72.168
[11] 74.168 76.168 78.168 80.621 85.444 90.694
```

---

**Edit:** I have just seen that a lot nicer and simpler answer was given (with exact same results). The only cause I am not deleting my complicated answer is that my loop checks also if adding a small number to a diff between two numbers would work better instead of always subtracting `2-diff()` from smaller values.

I hope my solution could operate better used at real data :)

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the nice answer anyway.